# hapijs - route config 'id' attribute - won't accept string value

Tags: hapi.js

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, so I'm asking here, rather than submitting a bug report.

In the documentation for the latest version of hapijs (16.1.1)

https://hapijs.com/api#serverlookupid

For server.lookup, it clearly indicates that an 'id' property can be a string.

```
const route = server.lookup('root');
```

However strings are expressively forbidden by the actual implementation code.

https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L340

```
Hoek.assert(id && typeof id === 'string', 'Invalid route id:', id);
```

Am I missing something here? Is this a bug, or an error in the documentation, or am I simply misunderstanding something?

It seems an strange limitation to impose. Strings are a lot more logical for a route id.

The other issue, is that in the index.d.ts, it specifically forces the use of a string parameter.

This functionality just seems completely broken. How am I supposed to use it, if when creating a route I need to use a numeric id, and then when trying to retrieve it I'm forced to use a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the assert backwards. The error message only displays if the assertion fails. If an id is provided it can only be of type string.

Comment: Thanks, yes of course. The issue turned out to be outdated type definitions. Even though @types/hapi claimed to be version 16.0.0, it was valid only for a much earlier version of hapijs.